# Puedo modificar los errores que te da PHP?

Tags: php

Mi pregunta es que estoy practicando creando cosas para ir aprendiendo y me surgio la duda si se pueden modificar los errores que te lanza PHP por ejemplo:

El error que daria PHP seria este:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ejemplo' for key 'userid'

Y quiero saber si lo puedo modificar a mi gusto para que dija por ejemplo:
"Ese valor ya esta registrado."

SOLUCIONADO pero tengo otra duda: Hice este verificador funciona correctamente pero no se si lo hice de la mejor manera posible.

```
try{
    $conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=privatedata","root","");
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid= :userid";
    $useridchecker=$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $userid=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usuario']));
    $useridchecker->bindValue(":userid", $userid);
    $useridchecker->execute();
    $uidcheck=$useridchecker->rowCount();
    if ($uidcheck!=0){
        echo "El usuario ingresado ya fue registrado, escoga otro.";
    }else{
        $sql1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= :email";
        $emailchecker=$conexion->prepare($sql1);
        $email=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['email']));
        $emailchecker->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $emailchecker->execute();
        $echeck=$useridchecker->rowCount();
        if ($echeck!=0) {
            echo "El correo ingresado ya fue registrado, escoga otro.";
        }else{
            $userf=$_POST['usuario'];
            $emailf=$_POST['email'];
            $passf=$_POST['password'];
            $sql2="INSERT INTO users (userid,email,pass) VALUES ('$userf','$emailf','$passf')";
            $registrar=$conexion->prepare($sql2);
            $registrar->execute();
            header("Location: ../login.php");
        }
    }

}catch (Exception $e){
    die("El error es: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es antes de la inserción verificar si el valor ya existe. Si no existe, lo insertas, si ya existe imprimes la leyenda que quieres. No se trata de cambiar los errores, más bien de diseñar tu sistema para evitar esos errores

Comment: ¿Esto lo estás preguntando para modificar **dentro** de PHPMyAdmin, o en tu código PHP? (si es el 2do, deberías eliminar la etiqueta [tag:phpmyadmin] de la pregunta)

Comment: @ReneLimon Entiendo, estaba planeando hacer eso pero queria saber si habia una forma mas facil de hacerlo gracias :)

Comment: los errores de PHP son para el desarrollador, no para el usuario.

Comment: Si vas a manejar excepciones de MySQL, una vez yo hice una clase estática que contenía los String con los mensajes de error personalizados. Cuando ejecutaba consultas, en un bloque `catch` llamaba un la función de dicha clase que evaluaba el error y devolvía el mensaje.

Comment: @ReneLimon Actualice  mi post ese fue mi verificador si funciona pero lo hice de la manera correcta?

Comment: Si quieres mensajes personalizados, es buena idea lo que dice @Acentellao17, creas una clase, le pasas el código de error y en base a ese código devuelves un mensaje personalizado si dicho código de error se encuentra dentro de tu clase personalizada, y si no se encuentra, devuelves el mensaje de error por defecto. Aunque recomiendo que tengas mucho cuidado con eso, en el pasado, ahora mismo no sabría decirte si ya corrigieron eso, PDO mostraba en pantalla las credenciales de conexión en los mensajes de error si no tenías bien configurado el manejo de errores...

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu respuesta investigare sobre el team no soy tan experto en php yo me consideria principiante asi que investigare lo que me dicen.